# Slim Framework app is runned when a relative file is in the page

Tags: php, slim

When a page is requested that contains files / images with relative paths the app will run for every request. So the app is bootstrapped and executed multiple times.

The probleem seems to occur when Images have an underscore in the file name

```
<img src="assets/images/_download.jpg" alt="test">
<img src="assets/images/_downlaod2.jpg" alt="test">
<img src="assets/images/_downlod3.jpg" alt="test">
```

I noticed this because I am using Xdebug. I wonder how this can be prevented and what the best practices are?

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
  # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
  # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
  # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
  # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
  # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
  # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
  # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

  # If the above doesn't work you might need to set the `RewriteBase` directive manually, it should be the
  # absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
  # RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is a server issue, check your .htaccess file or Nginx config file

Comment: Thank you for the reply; I have the same problem on an Nginx and Apache server. I have updated the question with new information. The problem increases when there are multiple images with a '_' in the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the folder condition:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

It prevents a rewrite in the case the request resolves to a folder. So per your `htaccess` code, all requests are being rewritten to the `index.php` file, except for those that resolve to a file. Since your images live inside a folder, they resolve to a folder first.

Your rewrite should look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```